# Does iCheck prevents any parent click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, icheck

I have an implementation of an "interaction tracker", that sends anonymous basic data about what elements of the page were clicked.

I do so by adding an event listener for click on body, which works all right with any element on my website.

Curiously, on any iCheck element, the click event does not trigger. Is there any `preventDefault();` code on iCheck click events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the documentation of iCheck, they provide callbacks for when a checkbox is clicked. Try hooking into those to detect a click.

[iCheck documentation - Callbacks](http://icheck.fronteed.com/#callbacks)

Example from their documentation:

```
$('input').on('ifChecked', function(event){
    alert(event.type + ' callback');
});
```

Comment: I see that. But I was expecting to understand this issue. Hooking directly would create an exception, since all my tracking happens on a single event listener in a separate module.

Comment: I did find this: https://github.com/fronteed/iCheck/issues/211 Are you using v1 or v2? Seems like no-one really has a perfect answer for this.

Comment: I'm on v1 actually. I tried to quickly move to v2 to check the changes, but still didn't work. I'll try again to fully move to v2, biggest problem is that on bower it is still on v1.